# Multiple uri to same post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, uri

I wanted to make two uri to point same post in Wordpress but without redirect, 
mysite.co.uk/awesome-post
mysite.co.uk/?p=12

I want those two uri to be pointed to same post but when you reach the page uri shouldn't change.

Comment: Just curious...why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: My client wants to count Facebook likes per post but it's impossible, because Facebook like counts are not only counts likes its counting share as likes. So I'm gonna do create two entirely different uri but same post then put separate buttons. So likes will be never effect with shares.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is you want to duplicate the post content because all you need is the same content, different URL's and a different like button. Thinking about it make this reasonable, everything should be different but the text.. i recommend maybe to install a SEO plugin so one of the posts would be hidden from search engines and than you'll be set to go.

Comment: What is the name of this plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that i know is duplicate your post and get second link from it and hide the duplicate from loop and if you wish back end.

for that you have to use [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action and plugin/theme activation hook for duplicate posts that have already published (this can be init hook but with caution you need to do this **only one time**).

first you have to loop through all posts and make duplicate

```
add_action('switch_theme', 'your_prefix_setup_options');

function your_prefix_setup_options () {
  // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array (
        'post_type'              => array( 'post' )
    );

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            // duplicate post like this
            your_prefix_post_duplicate( get_the_ID(), get_the_title(), get_the_content(), get_post_thumbnail_id() );

        }

    } else {
        // no posts found
    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

function your_prefix_post_duplicate($post_id, $title, $content, $attachment){


    $post_id = $post_id;
    $post_name = $title;
    $content = $content;
    $attachment = $attachment;


    $slug = str_replace( " ", "-", $post_name );
    $slug = strtolower($slug);

    $post_data = array(
        'post_content' => $content,
        'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
        'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
        'post_author'       =>  0,
        'post_name'     =>  $slug,
        'post_title'        =>  $post_name,
        'post_status'       =>  'published',
        'post_type'     =>  'post'
    );

    $prefix = 'your_prefix__';
    //create your duplicate post
    $duplicate_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
    set_post_thumbnail( $duplicate_post_id, $attachment );
    add_post_meta( $duplicate_post_id, $prefix . 'duplicate', TRUE );
    //get duplicate link
    $perma_link = get_permalink ( $duplicate_post_id );


    //set this link to your post as meta
    add_post_meta( $post_id, $prefix . 'duplicate_url', $perma_link );

}

// now you can get second uri for fb like/share
$second_link = get_post_meta(get_post_ID(),$prefix . 'duplicate_url', true);

//and you can use the meta and ignore duplicate post from showing on loop 
// or in advance you can use pre get post to hidethese duplicates from front end & back end permanently
get_post_meta(get_post_ID(),$prefix . 'duplicate', true);
```

Comment: Please read the answer its there, you can use save post hook to create duplicate for the new post each time when save_post action runs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer